# Append list to a python list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to run a random walk on a two-dimensional grid with four equiprobable actions [right(1), left(-1), upward(1), downward(-1)]. As the random walker moves forward, I want to store its location (x, y coordinates) in the list ***totSteps***. The x,y coordinates (that is, current location)  will be updated on every step as a variable ***curr_loc***. As you can see in the printed output, the first list (***curr_loc***) is the updated current location, and the second list (***totSteps***) supposedly contains the steps taken so far. There were 5 steps taken, and as such we have 10 outputs. Every time I append the ***curr_loc*** to ***totSteps***; all the previous coordinates get replaced with the current one. What's the reason?

```
steps = [1,-1,1,-1]
totSteps = [] # stores all the 5 steps taken but doesn't work 
# random walk with four steps left, right, 
# upward, downward on two dimensional grid
curr_loc = [0,0]
N = 5

for i in range(N):
    ranNums = np.random.randint(0,4) # picks one of four actions 
    if ranNums == 0 or ranNums == 1: # change x-coordinate
        curr_loc[0] += steps[ranNums] # taking the step 
        print(curr_loc) # current location of random walker 
        totSteps.append(curr_loc)
        print(totSteps) # append current location of random walker 
    elif ranNums == 2 or ranNums == 3: # chanfe y-coordinate 
        curr_loc[1] += steps[ranNums]
        print(curr_loc)
        totSteps.append(curr_loc) 
        print(totSteps)
```

> The output of the code is given below:

```
>[1, 0] # curr_loc
>[[1, 0]] # totSteps
>[1, -1]
>[[1, -1], [1, -1]]
>[1, 0]
>[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
>[1, -1]
>[[1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1]]
>[0, -1]
>[[0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1]]
```

Comment: You're appending the same `curr_loc` to the list every iteration. Try `totSteps.append(curr_loc[:])`

Comment: Thanks. It works. When I print ```curr_loc``` in the iteration, it prints out the updated value. I still don't understand why all previous values get *replaced* with the current value. Python ```append``` method appends the value (or list) to the end of list.

Comment: @fireshadow52's answer is good at explaining it :) Basically, you're adding the same one reference to the output list, so any change to any of the list affects all other lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further expand on @AndrejKesely's answer, you're not defining a new `list` object when a new loop iteration starts, and so whenever you change the values in `curr_loc`, since you're essentially appending another reference to `curr_loc` to `totSteps`, you have five references to the same object and that's why you're getting the same values.

Andrej's solution of `curr_loc[:]` means that you're effectively making a copy of the entire list and storing that rather than a reference to `curr_loc`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I had never faced this issue before. I don't have much experience, but I think the concept of reference is common in C++. I will look into it further.

Comment: No worries! Yes, "pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference" are common in C++ as well, but there it's a bit more obvious when a function parameter is a reference parameter.

Comment: Yes. I need to look into it closely. I spent so much time figuring out the issue.